# How do i extract texts from string and save it as two columns and add character at the end for third column

Tags: t-sql, azure-synapse

I m using TSQL, I want to extract text from the string and save it as two column and third one as

[image: Table_Name - Column to be extracted]

[image: Splitted in to two colum and third colum added __GM]

The following code is not complete but just getting rid of PRD1T_ the Finapp and not sure how to cater for rest of the text

```
Select substring(Table_name,
charindex('_',Table_name)+1,
Len(Table_name) - charindex('.',Table_name)) as Landing_Schema_Name
FROM [e].[Load_History_test]
```

Comment: You cannot use Transact SQL directly to extract text from image. Your first step should be to have a table with data. Same go for us! Please provide queries to create the tables and insert the sample data instead of images. In addition we need to know what is your excepted result. Note: I assume that you are using azure synapse dedicated - if this not the case, then what is the source of the data? Thanks.

Comment: No i don't want to extract text from image, first screenshot shows the column name(Table_Name) from source and i want to split that using sub string and create two columns as Landing_Schema_Name and Source_Table_Name

Comment: As I wrote above, we need simple queries to create the tables and insert the sample data, and not screenshots or description of the table and columns. Take your few seconds and write queries. If you do not know how to CREATE tables or INSERT rows then we first need to help you with this. Please inform us if this is an issue for you (SSMS has a tool to provide the queries to create the tables)

Comment: INSERT INTO Utility.CDC_Load_Register
       ( 
    [Table_Name]
                ,[Loaded_On]
     )
      Select substring(Table_name,
charindex('_',Table_name)+1,
Len(Table_name) - charindex('.',Table_name)) as Landing_Schema_Name,
SUBSTRING(e. [Table Name],y) AS Source_Table_Name,
SUBSTRING(e. [Table Name],y) & ”__GM” AS Landing_Table_Name,
(e.[Loaded On]) AS Replication_Commenced_DT,
NULL AS Record_Updated_DT
  FROM [e].[Load_History_test] as e

Comment: i figured out the syntax fro extracting, it works, Thanks Ronen Select 
  SUBSTRING(Table_name, LEN(LEFT(Table_name, CHARINDEX ('_', Table_name))) + 1, LEN(Table_name) - LEN(LEFT(Table_name, 
  CHARINDEX ('_', Table_name))) - LEN(RIGHT(Table_name, LEN(Table_name) - CHARINDEX ('.', Table_name))) - 1) as Landing_Schema_Name,
 Substring(Table_name, Charindex('.', Table_name)+1, LEN(Table_name)) as  Source_Table_Name,
Substring(Table_name, Charindex('.', Table_name)+1, LEN(Table_name)) + '__GM' as  Landing_Table_Name,

from [e].[Task_Load_History_test] as e

Comment: If you found the solution then add it as an answer and mark it as answer, so other people will not come and spend their time on reading the entire thread :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When asking questions like this it is best to provide some sample data and expected results, as Ronen suggested.  For SQL questions a really good way of doing this is with a temp table and sample data, like this:

```
CREATE TABLE #load_history_test ( 
    table_name  VARCHAR(100)
);

INSERT INTO #load_history_test 
SELECT 'PRD1T_FINAPP.HOLCONTRACT'
UNION ALL
SELECT 'PRD1T_FINAPP.TOCCASE'
UNION ALL
SELECT 'PRD1T_FINAPP.TOCCASE';
```

So that provides something people can run and starts towards the criteria for a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), which is the secret to getting a good answer on StackOverflow.  I have used `SELECT` with `UNION ALL` as Azure Synapse does not currently support the `VALUES` clause for multiple records.

For expected results, it's often good to display them in a table, something like this:

| col1 | col2 | col3 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| PRD1T | FINAPP | HOLCONTRACT |
| PRD1T | FINAPP | TOCCASE |

This way it's clear to people what you expect.  It is not clear why you have two `TOCCASE` examples in your screenprint.

For your problem, there is more than one approach.  You are along the right lines with `CHARINDEX`, `SUBSTRING` and `LEFT` but things can start to look complicated.  Therefore I tend to wrap up some complexity in a Common Table Expression (CTE), see below for an example.  There is also a kind of 'trick' approach with a built-in SQL function called `PARSENAME`.  This is designed to extract from four-part object names common in SQL Server eg `<server-name>.<database-name>.<schema-name>.<object-name>`.  As long as your object names will never have more than four parts, this approach will work for you.  See the main help for `PARSENAME` [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/parsename-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15).  See below for a complete demo that runs end to end with a temp table to demonstrate the different principles:

```
IF OBJECT_ID('#load_history_test') IS NOT NULL
    DROP TABLE #load_history_test;

CREATE TABLE #load_history_test ( 
    table_name  VARCHAR(100)
);

INSERT INTO #load_history_test 
SELECT 'PRD1T_FINAPP.HOLCONTRACT'
UNION ALL
SELECT 'PRD1T_FINAPP.TOCCASE'
UNION ALL
SELECT 'PRD1T_FINAPP.TOCCASE';


;WITH cte AS (
SELECT 
    table_name AS original_table_name,
    CHARINDEX( '_', table_name ) underscorePos,
    CHARINDEX( '.', table_name ) stopPos,
    REPLACE( table_name, '_', '.' ) AS clean_table_name
FROM #load_history_test
)
SELECT
    *,
    PARSENAME( clean_table_name, 3 ) a,
    PARSENAME( clean_table_name, 2 ) b,
    PARSENAME( clean_table_name, 1 ) c,
    LEFT( original_table_name, underscorePos - 1 )  getItemBeforeUnderscore,
    SUBSTRING( original_table_name, underscorePos + 1, ( ( stopPos - 1 ) - underscorePos ) ) AS getItemAfterUnderscore,
    SUBSTRING( original_table_name, stopPos + 1, 99 )  getItemAfterStop
FROM cte;
```

Comment: Thanks Bob, Sure i will provide the sample data and expected output onwards